# Why opening cmd.exe causes to run 2 processes?

Tags: cmd.exe, process, task-manager

Before:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAAwe.png]

After:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zto8Y.png]

As you can see the number of processes increases by 2 from 103 to 105 processes! Why should it increase by 2? I only ran `cmd.exe` which is by far one process!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`conhost.exe` is also started when you run `cmd.exe`. Check [this MS-thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_other-protect_scanning/what-is-conhostexe/38a69fb8-ded2-4f35-85c5-4d69cb8d016b) for more info.

Comment: So why link to another post with the same question, instead of linking to the answer that was provided on that page?  e.g. https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4996/what-is-conhost.exe-and-why-is-it-running/

Comment: @Debra The question was why the process count goes up by two when starting one executable. The MS-link was just extra info for the curious one... (and in fact if you scroll down among all the answers in that particular thread you'll notice that you don't even have to leave answers.microsoft.com).

Answer (score 3):

When you run `cmd.exe`, a second process called `conhost.exe` is always started. This is why you see 2 more processes. This [conhost.exe was added in Windows 7](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2009/10/05/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-console-host/), to increase security:

> In previous versions of Windows, all GUI activity on behalf of non-GUI
>   applications that ran on the desktop (console applications) was
>   brokered by the system process CSRSS.exe.  When a console application
>   wanted to receive characters, it called one of a small set of “Console
>   APIs” implemented in Kernel32.dll, and Kernel32 made an LPC call to
>   CSRSS.  CSRSS checked the input queue associated with the console
>   window and returned the appropriate character-mode input through
>   Kernel32 back to the console application.
>
> The problem with this was that even if an application ran in the
>   context of a regular user’s account, CSRSS.EXE runs under the Local
>   System account.  So it was possible under certain circumstances for
>   malware to exploit weaknesses in an application in order to execute
>   code under the more privileged Local System account in CSRSS.EXE. 
>   This kind of exploit is known as a “shatter attack” .
>
> **This exposure was addressed in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 by running the console messaging code in the context of a new process,
>   ConHost.exe. ConHost (Console Host) runs in the same security context
>   as its associated console application.  Instead of issuing an LPC
>   request to CSRSS for message-handling, the request goes to ConHost. 
>   As a result, any attempts to exploit the message-handing code of the
>   application will not result in an automatic escalation of
>   privileges.**

So calm down, everything is fine with your Windows.